# Visual C# Express Monogame load image

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, monogame, visual-c#-express-2010

I am new in monogame.
I loaded an image using `Texture2D background;`, then go to `LoadContent()` method and code `background  = Contect.Load<Texture2D>("background");`.  I then imported the image in the `Content` folder.
After that, I compiled it and got this error:
`Unable to load background assets`

I checked the Image, and it was background.bmp.

I'll keep on looking for a  solution for this.
If you have a solution for me please give me a link.
Any help is appreciated.  And by the way, I use Visual C# Express 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have 2 options, you can either add the content to the Content folder directly (if I understand correctly that's what you have done) or you can pre-compile the assets into XNB files first.

If you are using content directly you will need to add the file extension in code like so:

```
background = Contect.Load<Texture2D>("background.bmp");
```

And you'll also need to make sure you set the file to Content / Copy if newer in the properties window inside Visual Studio.

As a side note, if you are going to stick with this method I suggest you save your images as PNG files instead of BMP because PNG has lossless compression and supports transparency.

Alternately, you can pre-compile your content files first to store them in a more optimal file format. See https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki/MonoGame-Content-Processing

Answer (score -1):

Right click on the picture, go to Property and you will see. Copy to output. The default is don't copy you need to turn to Copy Always